# How to manipulate a linux file called [space][space].?

Tags: linux, scp

When I copy a file from a server using scp,

I mistakenly used the command

```
    scp xxx@xxxx:xx.zip  .
```

When I finished,I found that the file's name was  . and I cannot decompress
it.

Here is  the directory list.http://pfile.cn/4cxtf7

Comment: Are you sure that command actually worked? normally `.` is protected (since you can't move a file and overwrite a directory with it. and `[space]` is typically ignored in those commands.

Comment: @jkeuhlen Actually I am not sure.The scp command takes me about an afternoon.But I I just find the big file you can see on the pics.I don't know

Answer (score 2):

For escaping special characters (like space) use a backslash `\`

```
gunzip \ \ .
```

will work on file called [space][space][dot]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to escaping, you can also wrap the name in quotes:

```
mv '  .' better-name.zip
```